# Парсинг GeoLocation из Oracle APEX & OpenStreetMap

Tags: парсер, oracle, openstreetmap

Хотелось бы вытащить информацию о положении заявок на карте (в идеале после преобразований получить latitude & longitude) с сайта https://115.xn--90ais/ за 2019 год. Информация, которую я смог найти, представляет из себя следующее. Пример:

```
{
    "GEOMETRY": {
        "sdo_gtype": 2001,
        "sdo_srid": 3857,
        "sdo_point": {
            "x": "2905661.48115622",
            "y": "6821656.22875036",
            "z": "null"
        },
        "sdo_elem_info": "null",
        "sdo_ordinates": "null"
    }
}
```

Кажется, что у меня сейчас есть координаты, но не понятно, как можно достать карту (и можно ли), на которую их нужно нанести.

Ниже опишу метод, который позволяет получить след. координаты:

- Зайти на главную страницу
- Нажать на "Карта"
- Нажать на "Заявок, принятых через портал"
- Выбрать в форме "Период поступления" любой месяц 2019 года
- Открыть инспектор, перейти на вкладку Network
- При переключении по месяцам (либо изначально) будет 200 POST запрос, файл www_flow.ajax. В нем интересует поле GEOMETRY

Если сделать это нельзя, то тоже буду рад об этом узнать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у кого-то есть много свободного времени и желания разобраться в географии и Oracle Apex, то вот полезные ссылки:

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_objrelschema.htm
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48949/epsg-3857-or-4326-for-googlemaps-openstreetmap-and-leaflet

Само решение: существует конвертер из projected coordinates в долготу и широту - https://epsg.io/transform